# How to import CommonModule for root in standalone components appoach?

Tags: angular

I've recently started new application and found out information that Angular team is going to make standalone approach default and eventually get rid of modules. So I decided to rewrite my app.

However, I cannot use CommonModule in providers array inside of `main.ts`. Is there any way to import it globally and not in every component (or by routing)?

Here is my code that should work:

```
// main.ts

import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
import { importProvidersFrom } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [importProvidersFrom(CommonModule)],
});
```

```
// app.component.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  standalone: true,
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

```
<!-- app.component.html -->

<div *ngIf="true">TEST</div>
```

And I still get error:

```
src/app/app.component.html:1:7 - warning NG8103: The `*ngIf` directive was used in the template, but neither the `NgIf` directive nor the `CommonModule` was imported. Please make sure that either the `NgIf` directive or the `CommonModule` is included in the `@Component.imports` array of this component.

1 <div *ngIf="true">TEST</div>
        ~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.
```

I already tried to use `imports: [CommonModule]` in `@Component({})` decorator, but this is not a good solution, because this module will be used probably in every component, so this is just gonna be boilerplate.

Comment: You have to add import commonModule inside your component if the component is standalone, if the component is standalone then all the imports which that component required need to be added to that particular component it wont listen any other import.

Comment: @KamranKhatti I know this is special case because CommonModule is not 3rd party module, but it's still a module. Documentation says that we can import a module like I did (https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components#configuring-dependency-injection - last code example with LibraryModule). So shouldn't it work?

Answer (score 2):

The error you have is quite explicit, it's not a provider issue:

> Please make sure that either the `NgIf` directive or the
> `CommonModule` is included in the `@Component.imports` array of this
> component.

You need to either add `CommonModule` or `NgIf` in the `imports: []` of your standalone component.

Comment: this is exactly what I try to avoid and import CommonModule globally

Comment: That's not how standalone component work unfortunaltely.

Comment: so we have no option to global import something? I think this is really big inconvenience

Comment: When you think about it, it's much better as every component actually is standalone and defines its own dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

##### Approach 1:

In you standalone component module import Common Module like below :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MyStandaloneComponent } from './my-standalone-component.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyStandaloneComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule, // Import CommonModule here

  ],
  exports: [
    MyStandaloneComponent,
  ],
})
export class MyStandaloneComponentModule {}
```

And the you can then import `MyStandaloneComponentModule` in the module where you want to use `MyStandaloneComponent`, and `CommonModule` will be available for use within that module. Add this to your app.module like below :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MyStandaloneComponentModule } from './path/to/my-standalone-component.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MyStandaloneComponentModule, // Import MyStandaloneComponentModule here
    // other modules if any
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

##### Approach 2:

Directly import it your component like below:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
    @Component({
        standalone: true,
        imports: [CommonModule], // add common module here
        selector: 'example-component',
        template: `./example.component.html`,
    })
    export class ExampleComponent {}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just import CommonModule in your component and it will work.

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
```

and below that in the imports:

```
    @Component({
        standalone: true,
        imports: [CommonModule],
        selector: 'example-component',
        template: `./example.component.html`,
    })
    export class ExampleComponent {}
```