# importProvidersFrom([CommonModule] in Angular 17 Standalone Component

Tags: angular, angular17

```js
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    importProvidersFrom(
      [
        CommonModule
      ]
    )
  ]
```

Why can't CommonModule be entered in app.config.ts like this in Standalone components????? And should it be imported into the component itself?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cfuo2.jpg)

angular 17 standalone components , Import problem CommonModule

Comment: `importProvidersFrom()` can and should only be used in the app config, it makes no sense to use it in a standalone component. It also makes no sense to import providers from `CommonModule` as it has no providers. It is not clear to me what the problem is. It looks to me like a self-constructed problem.

Answer (score 1):

standalone are self-contained and declare their own dependencies, they use the imports property in the component decorator to directly import other standalone components, directives, and pipes they depend on.

if you wish use common directives like ngIf and so, you should import CommonModule directly in the component's imports array.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule], 
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.css']
})
export class MyComponent {
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in general:

- `BrowserModule` is for root `NgModule` and `CommonModule` is for feature `NgModule`
- instead of `CommonModule` you can utilize its standalone parts such as `NgIf`, `NgFor` and so on

many answers can be obtained online:

1. https://angular.io/guide/frequent-ngmodules
2. https://angular.io/guide/feature-modules
3. [How to import CommonModule for root in standalone components appoach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76706524/how-to-import-commonmodule-for-root-in-standalone-components-appoach)
4. [CommonModule vs BrowserModule in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49662864/commonmodule-vs-browsermodule-in-angular)
5. https://github.com/angular/angular.io/issues/2166