Why ngModel doesn't works on the last version of Angular 17?
I am trying to make a form in my angular app, but when i want to implement ngModel on my form :
    <form (ngSubmit)="onSignUp()" #signupForm="ngForm">
        <h1>Connexion</h1>
        <input type="email" name="mail" [(ngModel)]="userLogin.email" placeholder="Email" />
        <input type="password" name="mdp" [(ngModel)]="userLogin.password" placeholder="Password" />
        <a href="#">Mot de passe oublie ?</a>
        <button type="submit">Se Connecter</button>
    </form>

I have this error :
NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. [plugin angular-compiler]
I can't import FormsModule in the app.module.ts because this file doesn't exists on Angular 17, i only have an app.config.ts file.
Can someone please explain me how to do?

If your component is set with standalone: true, then you need to add FormsModule to the imports array of the component!
Since it's standalone, we need to add all the necessary dependencies to the imports array!
@Component({
  ...
 imports: [
      ...
      FormsModule,
      ...
  ],
  ...
})


i did same ,but still same issue

Angular standalone application doesn't support common modules directly, instead importing them separately under individual standalone components. This reduces the additional overhead of loading additional modules that are not using in a particular component.
If you are using Angular 17 or latest, follow the instructions:

Create a file named(any name) app.module.ts right under app directory of your angular project and write an array of common imported modules to the file.

import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";

export const AppModule = [
    FormsModule,
    CommonModule,
]


Now import the AppModule array where your components needed:

@Component({
  selector: 'app-standalone',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    AppModule
  ],
  templateUrl: './standalone.component.html',
  styleUrl: './standalone.component.scss'
})
export class StandaloneComponent {}

If you need more about the Module, please visit the link click here

If you have more query pls visit the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77926699/is-there-a-way-of-providing-the-common-module-in-all-modules-in-angular-standalo/79003957#79003957

Doest not work. A module is not just an array. And by doing what in @Component -> import, your import is an array of array wich is not supported by angular.

Dear @dolig, I also provide a link bellow where you can avail your purpose. Hope you not visited.
